# I can zoom by clicking image, but I can't position myself where the pointer clicks

Tags: javascript, zooming

I have an HTML file that shows an image, it contains a function that enlarges image to original size, so that it exceeds the window, but I would like to position myself in the area surrounding the pointer always, you know 'cause when zoom is activated, I am positioned in the left corner,

```
if  (document.getElementsByClassName("shrinkToFit1")[0].offsetHeight <= window.innerHeight)
                    {
                        document.getElementsByClassName("shrinkToFit1")[0].style.height="auto";}
```

Comment: can u draw your thoughts and send here?

Comment: I have an HTML file that shows an image, When zoom is activated, I am positioned in the left corner.

Comment: try to set position: absolute, top: 50%, left: 50%, transform: translate(-50%, -50%) to ur img

Comment: The enlarged image has the upper and left part amputated, or out of sight, new limits positioned in the upper left corner, my focus is always on the old central part that is bordering upper left corner.